# using libsvm classifier in Weka and heap size

Tags: heap-memory, classpath, weka, libsvm

problem in working with WEKA 3.6

I want to utilize libsvm.jar but the error "not in the classpath" occurs when I run weka with the command prompt as below:

java -Xmx900m -jar Weka.jar

please note that we use libsvm library when I run weka in normal mode (with the initial heap size and without using command prompt). 
besides, I use windows 7-32bit.

help me plz I am running out of time.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Find out where `libsvm.jar` is and include it in the classpath, e.g.

```
java -Xmx900m -classpath '.:/usr/share/java/libsvm.jar' -jar Weka.jar
```

The actual location of `libsvm.jar` will depend on your system.

Comment: thanks,I already updated the CLASSPATH (environment variable) in Windows and its value is:>'.;C:\Weka3-6\wlsvm.jar;C:\Weka3-6\libsvm.jar' and so I can use libsvm library when i run weka without increased heap,However, I utilize your code as below: >java -Xmx900m -classpath 'C:\Weka3-6\libsvm.jar' -jar 'C:\Weka3-6\Weka.jar' but i get the following disappointing error: > Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Files Caused by:java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Files at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source) Could not find the main class ... : Files.Program will exit

Comment: Try adding the current path to the classpath as well: `'.;/path/to/libsvm'`.

Comment: thanks for your quick reply, I copied the libsvm.jar in both ./bin directory of java and weka3-6. the current path is C:\Weka3-6\\ and "C:\Weka3-6\libsvm.jar" is in CLASSPATH. So, should i add another path?...

Comment: It should work if the path to the libsvm jar and the weka jar are in the classpath.

Comment: thanks anyway i think i should change my windows and install java again it may solve that

Answer (score 0):

The other answer wasn't working for me. According to the [Weka documentation](http://weka.wikispaces.com/LibSVM), to include LibSVM in the classpath requires not using the "-jar weka.jar" option. Specifying -jar overrides the classpath that you are trying to set.

Instead,  use

```
java -Xmx900m -classpath $CLASSPATH:weka.jar:libsvm.jar weka.gui.GUIChooser
```